# What should be the path to the file while using #attached in a custom_module_block_view()?

Tags: javascript, blocks

I have created a custom module and was trying to add javascript file to a block using #attached method which was described [here](http://www.jaypan.com/tutorial/adding-css-and-js-cached-block-drupal-7). I am confused with the Path/to/file as I have tried to give a full path which is `"/var/www/html/sites/all/modules/custom_module/js/file.js"`. and shorter path `"js/file.js"`

but it doesn't load.

It just say `file_get_contents("/var/www/html/sites/all/modules/custom_module/js/file.js"): unable to load, no such file or folder present /var/www/html/common.inc .....`

Why I am getting the file_get_contents error when I am not using this method?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `drupal_get_path()` function to construct the path of your asset file (in your case the JS file).

To include the `YOUR_MODULE.js` file which sits in a subfolder `js`, part of your custom module

```
$block = array
(
    'subject' => t('My block title'),
    'content' => array(
        '#markup' => '<p>' . t('This is some text that will go in the block.') . '</p>',
        '#attached' => array(
            'js' => array(drupal_get_path('module', 'YOUR_MODULE_NAME') . '/js/YOUR_MODULE.js'),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: Hi Mike, Thanks for the reply. I have tried this way but I still get the same warning, <<Warning: file_get_contents(/js/file.js): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in drupal_build_js_cache() (line 4947 of /var/www/html/includes/common.inc).>>
2) How do I make sure if the file has been called or the file has been added?

Comment: Well if you got the warning, it means the file you are trying to load doesn't exist. Did you create the `file.js` under `js` directory in your custom module directory?

Comment: yes my module was "/var/www/html/sites/all/modules/custom_module/" and my file was here "/var/www/html/sites/all/modules/custom_module/js/file.js" I tried the "drupal_add_js" as well but it didn't work. I don't know, I may have done something wrong. But at the end I got it working by adding it to theme.info file.
But I want it to be appear only on front page, not on all the pages. I assume theme.info add it to every webpage.

Comment: Well, in your case it should work using: `'js' => array(drupal_get_path('module', 'custom_module') . '/js/file.js'),`. Yes, exactly, adding it in the `theme.info` will add it on every page.

Comment: Yeah I tried this way. I don't know why it didn't work. How do you verify if this method works? I assume if it finds the file, we can look using the "inspect element" in Chrome and then if we go to "Network". I verified it there, it didn't load the file.js